# RewriteRule for one file only

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically I have the htaccess below. At the minute it works perfectly, but it redirects every file. For example foo.php to /foo when I only want it to redirect about.php to /about. Basically I want to force the .php extension to be removed for about.php but only that file.

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /about [R,L]
```

Now I have the above code. It now causes a too many redirects error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it myself.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} about.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
```

That's your correct *rewrite*, which means that a request to `/about` will be handled as if it were a request to `/about.php`:

And as for this separate issue:

> I don't want the user to see about.php even if he types that in

you will need a *redirect* from `/about.php` to `/about`. That's what your second and third line do (RewriteRule with `[R]` flag for redirection), but the condition is way to broad and also contains some superfluent stuff:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

Change it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /about [R,L]
```

> Does this keep GET params?

If you add the `[QSA]` flag (query string append), yes.

**Update**

As @PeterWooster pointed out, the redirect part can be simplified to:

```
Redirect /about.php /about
```

Comment: This is great if you need conditions and regex, but the redirect Directive is designed for the OP's use case.

Comment: @PeterWooster you are totally right, I was too biased by the original rules, now they don't make much sense anymore (though it works).

Comment: See my answer a few minutes ago.  I use this all the time for SEO site moves.  But the rewrite based version is nice when you need the regex.

Comment: +1 I think this (First part) is the right answer. Not sure about the mod_alias, though. Check this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) for: "...mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such **as manipulating the query string, use the tools provided by mod_rewrite**."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Redirect rule to do this, it is really simple. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Edit:
This causes the server to send a redirect to the client, if the 301 status is used this is particularly useful for SEO when moving a site.

Example from apache docs:

Redirect /service http://foo2.example.com/service

Comment: The redirect Directive in that apache doc does what you want, it does a 301 redirect. The user ends up with the target address in their browser location.

Comment: I don't normally use query parms but just tried one and it does.  Take a look at http://acvu.ca/2_about.html?foo=bar  it redirects to a qa site of mine and retains the query parms.  I just used a simple redirect 301 old new.